# sending one time message from background page to devtool page

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I have been working on chrome extension which requires message passing at some times to trigger some events on current web page.

I have been using chrome.runtime.sendMessage to send message from devtool page  to background page. and on background page i am getting those messages using chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener and it is working.

but i am not able to send message from background page to devtools page using this !
how can i send one time message from background page to devtool page ?

devtool.js

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request){
if(request.name=="xyz")
{
    alert("HI");
}
});
```

background.js

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
    name : "xyz"
});
```

Can someone help with it ?

Comment: Based from this [forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/google-chrome-developer-tools/Q3DbtWRlgLo/kEYPaW8h0sgJ), you can't use `chrome.extension.sendMessage()` to send a message to an extension page running in the context of DevTools. The best way to communicate from background page to DevTools is to open a port from the DevTools page using `chrome.extension.connect` and use port.postMessage() in the background page later.

Comment: @abielita _Please_ make that comment into an answer (but note that `extension` should be replaced by `runtime`)

Answer (score 0):

Based from this [forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/google-chrome-developer-tools/Q3DbtWRlgLo/kEYPaW8h0sgJ), you can't use `chrome.runtime.sendMessage()` to send a message to an extension page running in the context of DevTools. The best way to communicate from background page to DevTools is to open a port from the DevTools page using `chrome.runtime.connect` and use `port.postMessage()` in the background page later.

Answer (score 0):

If your interested, I have created a small library that does all the work for you and lets you easily send messages across any extension parts (specifically in your case, from background to the devtool).

You can check it out here: [chrome-ext-messenger](https://www.npmjs.com/package/chrome-ext-messenger)

Feel free to contact me if you have any questions on how to use it.